# Shortest path with a start vertex that touches all nodes at least once with repeats allowed

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, graph-traversal

I tried looking this problem up for quite a bit now, but can't seem to find a whole lot of discussion about this. At first it sounded like the TSP to me, but I don't think so (it's much harder to do I believe). Maybe I am over thinking this though? I'm not looking for the fastest solution, but I fear a brute-force algorithm may take an extremely long time to perform this on a undirected graph with say 30 nodes. I'm personally trying to figure out on a video game the fastest way to traverse through every spawn point of a monster on a given zone (with a start point of course) so I can find him faster. I've already constructed a graph and figured out the distances assuming a complete graph. I guess on my part, one way to reduce the run time of such an algorithm is to remove realistically what edges wouldn't and probably wouldn't be included in a optimal path. I assume adding lots of constraints could help too. Might anyone know if there's a specific name for this problem, or if there is a simpler approach aside from just the standard brute-force? Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify whether the path should go back to the start vertex? Are you interested in approximation algorithm?

Comment: From your description it is not clear why this is not a TSP problem.

Comment: Sorry I should've said it explicitly. We don't want to go back to the start vertex, we just want to touch everything once!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is just a TSP in disguise.

### 1. Dealing with "visit each node at least once"

First, compute a modified distance matrix $D(i,j)$, $i,j=1,...,n$ using an all-pairs shortest path algorithm, such as the Floyd-Warshall algorithm. That is, you want $D(i,j)$ to be the shortest path length from node $i$ to node $j$. Using Floyd-Warshall you also compute a matrix $S(i,j)$ that gives the successor of $i$ on the shortest path from $i$ to $j$.

Now apply a TSP algorithm to the distance matrix $D$. This will give you a tour $T$ that goes through each node exactly once. You now expand each step of $T$ into a shortest path (you can do this using the matrix $S$). That is, if some step of $T$ goes from $i$ to $j$, you expand it into the shortest path from $i$ to $j$. Concatenating all these paths gives a tour $T'$ that visits each node at least once, with possible repeats. If $T$ is optimal for $D$, then $T'$ must be optimal for the original graph.

### 2. Dealing with "the tour does not need to return to the starting node"

Preprocess your graph as follows. Add a dummy node, node 0, such that the distance from 0 to the starting node $s$ is 0 and the distance from node 0 to any other node is $M := n \cdot \max_{i,j} D(i,j)$.

Now find a TSP tour on the modified graph using your TSP algorithm of choice. 
Because the value of $M$ is so large, any optimal TSP tour will be of the form
$$ 0, s, \pi(1), ..., \pi(n-1), 0$$
where $\pi$ is some permutation of the nodes excluding the start node and node 0. Then the sequence $s, \pi(1), \ldots, \pi(n-1)$ represents your solution.

### 3. Exact vs heuristic

You can use any algorithm for the symmetric TSP problem. If $n$ is about 30, you will probably not be able to apply an exact (= optimal) TSP algorithm such as the [Held-Karp dynamic programming algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm#Dynamic_programming_approach). A very simple yet reasonable  heuristic you might want to try is [2-OPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-opt), which is straightforward to program. A [branch-and-bound](http://lcm.csa.iisc.ernet.in/dsa/node187.html) approach might also work well in practice.

Comment: I guess a question then to ask is, what's the last step to not return to the start node?

Comment: Thank you for the amazing details :) I wish I could upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation!